# Is there any need to use prepare statement in select query?

Tags: php, sql, select, mysqli, prepared-statement

**I use often simple method in select query and i do not use prepare statement because i think there is no need to use prepare statement in select because in select we view the table . further tell me I think right or we should use prepare statment in select query also?**

If yes please Tell me

Comment: Just to avoid SQL injection attacks you should use them

Comment: If your query is _not_ using inputs from outside your database or application then in principle there is no chance of injection attacks, and you don't need a prepared statement.

Comment: There are two main advantages of prepared statements: 1. Protection against SQL injection attacks as already mentioned 2. A performance gain if you need one and the same query multiple times; in this case the execution path is just calculated once. If no external input and just querying once than there's neither need for (as mentioned already, too) nor benefit from...

Comment: Here are some [examples](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) to show how injection can occur

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's a VERY bad misconception. Given an average php user never can tell what is "outside input", this suggestion is a straight road to SQL injection.

Answer (score -2):

it is not necessary when there is no user input. It can sometimes still be useful to use a prepared statement when there is input though, even if it's not user input. This is because preparing a statement allows it to be executed more efficiently if it is run lots of times with different data each time

My mother says: the mountain that can be seen is not far away, don't stop trying

Comment: Given you cannot provide an exhaustive definition for whatever "user input", your suggestion is void and has zero application.